# Add a column in SQL LITE up to a certain number using SQL statements in python

Tags: sqlite, pycharm, python-3.7

I'm having trouble with this line of code. Basically, what I want to do is add a column in a database (SQL LITE), and use SQL inside of Python to add that column until it reaches a certain value and state the name of the person it reaches that value by.

I've used a whole bunch of different orders of commands like and switched the order of the columns listed in the statement below, which didn't help, so this is the one I've had the most progress with.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("Boys.db")
c = conn.cursor()
# Creating the table
class Table:
 c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (Rank INTEGER, Name INTEGER, TotalB INTEGER, Percentage INTEGER)
''')

c.execute('SELECT Name FROM Users GROUP BY Name HAVING SUM(Percentage) 
 > .5000')
rows = c.fetchall()
print('The boys who had a frequency of over 50% was...')
print(rows)

conn.commit()
# Loading in the csv data
csvfile = open('BoysCSVfromText.csv', 'r')
creader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for t in creader:
   c.execute('INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?,?,?,?)', t)
conn.close()
```

That statement prints out all the names of the boys that have a percent over 50% and in order from A-Z.

I have the sum of the whole column (percentage)using:

```
c.execute('SELECT SUM(Percentage) FROM Users')
rows = c.fetchall()
print('The boys who had a frequency of over 50% was...')
print(rows)
```

Which isn't what I want, so now I'm stuck.
My database is 1000 lines, so I can't have all of it in a picture, but this is what I have so far:

[Example of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFkw1.jpg)
[Example of the line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFkw1.jpg)

Hopefully, I've provided all the images that would be needed.

What I want to happen is that the SQL statement goes down the column "Percentage" from my database, and adds all of the numbers until it reaches the value .5000 and prints out the last name that it added when it reached that .5000 count. What is happening instead is that it prints out all of the boys names that are above .5000 in A-Z order. I'm thinking that it's because the group by statement groups it by the names that have over .5000 for their percentage.

Comment: I think you are searching for windowed `SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ...)` to calculate running total

Comment: may be clearer to say you want to sum a column or add up a column, "add a column" sounds like you want to do `alter table`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda so would it be like: Select SUM(Percentage) OVER(PARTITION BY Name? I don't know if I'd need order by, because all I really want is it to print out a name when it reaches that value.

Comment: Please provide a table definition and sample rows as a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements in your question for easy testing. Hard to work with an image.

Comment: You need an order for your data so you can have a non arbitrary *first* value. SQL tables are conceptually unordered sets without it.

Comment: Edited with everything, @Shawn. The CSV file is essentially everything like what the db image shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use a windowed `SUM` which is supported by [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(Percentage) OVER(ORDER BY Rank) AS p
  FROM Users
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE p > 0.5
ORDER BY p
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi Lukasz, when I replace Rank with Percentage, it shows Rank 874 and p as .5215, is that what I'm looking for? Did that basically add the whole column and stop at the name of the person where it passed .5?

Comment: @JG3356 Yes, it is running total ascending by Rank. To see full resultset you coud run only `SELECT *, SUM(Percentage) OVER(ORDER BY Rank) AS p
  FROM Users` and adjust query if needed.

Comment: Szoda, how would I put this into a Python IDE?